# Draggable sprite in the SFML

Tags: sfml

How I can make sprites drag with mouse, using code? I'm writing code for Battleships game, and I need codes for dragging with the mouse.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to draw a sprite at all? Do you know how to capture mouse input? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yup, I know how to draw, but I have problems with the dragging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think first what should happen in dragging,

- Click the sprite
- Move the mouse while still holding they left button on the sprite

now that we have already listed that, we can now think on the second step, translating it into a pseudo code.

```
 if ( check here if the user is moving )
 {
     if ( check here if the user is holding left button )
     { 
         if ( check here if mouse is inside the sprite ) 
         {
              set the position to the mouse pointer. 
         }
     }
 }
```

did you get that? :)

Comment: Can you help with sfml code, but not with pseudo code? Cuz I also have pseudo code

Comment: We can't give you any code without having your code in the question / what you've tried

Comment: @AzizKobilov i suggest you to read tutorial on sfml website or get a book and read about AABB collision(Axis Align Bounding Box)